# Value attribute in the option tag is set to 0 even if I add another value

Tags: php, html

I have a small exercise to write for a uni class.

I wrote this code as a part of a form

```
            <tr>
                <td>Payment Type:</td>
                <td><select Name="Payment" form="myform">
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                    <option value="0">Monthly Payments</option>
                    <option value="1">Daily Payments</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and when I try to echo the value of the "Payment" on my PHP file, it only shows 0, even if I select Daily Payments. I tried echo on other values and they work just fine.

Comment: Please write question in brief and also add php code

Comment: @JatinKaklotar My question is "Why is the value set to 0, even if I select "Daily Payments" on the form? PHP code is this 
 `<?php 
       $CompanySales = $_POST['CompanySales'];
       $TypeofPayment =$_POST['Payment'];
       echo $TypeofPayment;
       $Payment = $_POST["Payment"];
?>`

Comment: @JatinKaklotar When I run the html file, I complete the form and select the "Daily Payments", then I click submit but the PHP file still shows 0 instead of 1 (as the value should have been).